# Python: extract text request from url

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, urlparse

I try to extract users requests from url. I try to search answer, but I only find how to parse string.
But I have a problem, that I should identify a lot of urls with request and when I try to get string with attribute, attributes with text are different.
I mean when I try

```
pat = re.compile(r"\?\w+=(.*)")
search = ['yandex.ru/search', 'youtube.com/results', 'google.com/search', 'google.ru/search', 'go.mail.ru/search', 'search.yahoo.com/search', 'market.yandex.ru/search', 'bing.com/search']
for i in urls:
    u = re.findall(pat, i)
    if any(ext in i for ext in search):
        if len(u) > 0:
            str = urllib.unquote(u[0])
            print str
            print {k: [s for s in v] for k, v in parse_qs(str).items()}
```

And it looks like

```
chromesearch&clid=2196598&text=королевы крика смотреть онлайн&lr=213&redircnt=1467230336.1
{'text': ['\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd1\x8b \xd0\xba\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0 \xd1\x81\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbd'], 'clid': ['2196598'], 'lr': ['213'], 'redircnt': ['1467230336.1']}
минималистичный+стиль&newwindow=1&biw=1280&bih=909&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikhI2M_s3NAhXBBiwKHfbEBEEQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=Er7qLiHoEGPIGM:
{'bih': ['909'], 'newwindow': ['1'], 'source': ['lnms'], 'ved': ['0ahUKEwikhI2M_s3NAhXBBiwKHfbEBEEQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=Er7qLiHoEGPIGM:'], 'tbm': ['isch'], 'biw': ['1280'], 'sa': ['X']}
минималистичный+стиль&newwindow=1&biw=1280&bih=909&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikhI2M_s3NAhXBBiwKHfbEBEEQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=Er7qLiHoEGPIGM:
{'bih': ['909'], 'newwindow': ['1'], 'source': ['lnms'], 'ved': ['0ahUKEwikhI2M_s3NAhXBBiwKHfbEBEEQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=Er7qLiHoEGPIGM:'], 'tbm': ['isch'], 'biw': ['1280'], 'sa': ['X']}
rjulf+ddjlbim+ytdthysq+gby+rjl+d+,fyrjvfn&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ezZ0V-7iOoab6ASvlJe4Dg
{'ie': ['utf-8'], 'oe': ['utf-8'], 'gws_rd': ['cr'], 'ei': ['ezZ0V-7iOoab6ASvlJe4Dg']}
маскаи гейла&lr=10750&clid=1985551-210&win=213
{'win': ['213'], 'clid': ['1985551-210'], 'lr': ['10750']}
1&q=как+выбрать+смартфон
{'q': ['\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba \xd0\xb2\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb1\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \xd1\x81\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd1\x82\xd1\x84\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd']}
Jade+Jantzen&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=FQB0V9WbIoahsAH5zZGACg
{'ie': ['utf-8'], 'oe': ['utf-8'], 'gws_rd': ['cr'], 'ei': ['FQB0V9WbIoahsAH5zZGACg']}
```

Is any way to get only text to all strings?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the text using a dictionary lookup to get the list, then access the first element of the list:

```
d = {'text': ['\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd1\x8b \xd0\xba\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0 \xd1\x81\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbd'], 'clid': ['2196598'], 'lr': ['213'], 'redircnt': ['1467230336.1']}
text = d['text'][0]

>>> print text
королевы крика смотреть онлайн
```

Or you can get it directly from the `parse_qs` result:

```
>>> print urlparse.parse_qs(s)['text'][0]
королевы крика смотреть онлайн
```

To apply that to your code such that it will work for all values:

```
print {k: v[0] for k, v in parse_qs(str).items()}
```

i.e. take the first item of each values list.

---

If you want to print the dictionaries and have the strings appear in the proper representation, i.e. not as produced by *repr*, you could use the `json` module to dump the dictionary objects as strings, then print them:

```
import json

d = {'text': ['\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd1\x8b \xd0\xba\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0 \xd1\x81\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbd'], 'clid': ['2196598'], 'lr': ['213'], 'redircnt': ['1467230336.1']}
s = json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False)

>>> print s
{"text": ["королевы крика смотреть онлайн"], "clid": ["2196598"], "lr": ["213"], "redircnt": ["1467230336.1"]}
```

Comment: Okey, but how can I extract text of requests from there?

Comment: @PetrPetrov: I've misunderstood your question. Accessing the text is a simple dictionary lookup.

Comment: I wrote my problem in the question. Can you see to the strings with attributed? In some string text in attribute `text`, some in attribute `q`, but some doens't contain in attribute (`маскаи гейла&lr=10750&clid=1985551-210&win=213
{'win': ['213'], 'clid': ['1985551-210'], 'lr': ['10750']}`). And I want to get text from all strings

Comment: @PetrPetrov: answer updated to show how to get the text from the `parse_qs()` result and use it to build a dictionary.

Comment: @PetrPetrov: sorry, but your question is extremely unclear. I think I understand now, check updated answer.